# Matching skin color of different images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photo-editing

[image]

How can I match the foreground face to the surrounding faces? I tried a couple of  color matching techniques, both Photoshop built-in and manual, but I suspect there is more than just the color to be matched (I also played with exposure and levels).

Comment: Problem here isn't really color, it's lighting. The background men are all lit form the a distance off to the left. The added man is lit closely directly from the front. You can't *easily* correct different lighting. Match the color perfectly and the lighting is still going to make the added image look added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a Hue/Saturation Adjustment layer. The mans face is a little too yellow and bright. He has highlights on his face that other people in that photo do not have.

Example Hue/Saturation settings:

Hue: -13

Saturation: -6

Lightness -8

I used a mask on the adjustment layer so it only effects the man in the fronts face. You can also use curves and a layer mask to even out the contrast on the mans face.

[image: layers panel]

Result

[image: result]